# synonym finder text-mining algorithm

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, synonym, corpus

I would like to create an automatic synonym finder algorithm (mostly for brand names).
For example, if the user enters the word "Coca cola", I would like to return the word "Coke".

This can easily be done using dictoniaries; but than I need a dictonary file for that.
How can I automaticly create one?
(I have a small corpus with 1 million+ records, the synonyms will come from this).

Are there any text-mining algorithms for this problems?
Also, there are some online synonym services for this, but these contain no brand names :-(

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: What do your records look like? Can you cluster your records to find similar terms?

Answer (score 0):

A trie based algorithm can find synonyms or similar words. It's not using keys but position in the tree to define the key. For example from A you go to B and from B you go to C. There are many data structures for a trie. The most simple is an adjaceny list or a ternary search tree.

Comment: How do you suggest finding "Coke" for "Coca cola" will work with tries? Ties would be greate for similary words/misspelled words, but I don't see how they can be used for synonims :-(

Comment: Show the first matched trees under letter C?

Comment: I fear there would be too much words returned :-(